# MarkLogic 10 - configure App Server, Forest and Database from remote location on the server

Tags: automation, marklogic, server-configuration, marklogic-10

I am looking for full automation right from configuring App Server, Forest, and Database. I found way to configure MarkLogic through configuration program as per https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin-api/configure

I am looking for a way that can be integrated into the build process as a part of automation which will take care of this one-time configuration for MarkLogic 10.

Answer (score 1):

ml-gradle might be what you're looking for:
https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle
"ml-gradle is a Gradle plugin that can automate everything you do with MarkLogic. Deploy an application, add a host..."